# Why does repartition give different number of partitions (than the default 200)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I tried to repartition a dataframe by column but it always returns a single partition.

**Spark config:**

I have tried both `local[*]` i.e. with 16 cores

after starting the spark instance, I check the partitions config by calling `spark.conf.get('spark.sql.shuffle.partitions')` and it gives 200 as expected

**Sample Dataframe**
I randomly create a dataframe by

```
simpleData = [("James","Sales","NY",90000,34,10000),
    ("Michael","Sales","NY",86000,56,20000),
    ("Robert","Sales","CA",81000,30,23000),
    ("Maria","Finance","CA",90000,24,23000),
    ("Raman","Finance","CA",99000,40,24000),
    ("Scott","Finance","NY",83000,36,19000),
    ("Jen","Finance","NY",79000,53,15000),
    ("Jeff","Marketing","CA",80000,25,18000),
    ("Kumar","Marketing","NY",91000,50,21000)
  ]

schema = ["employee_name","department","state","salary","age","bonus"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=simpleData, schema = schema)
```

**Partitions**

I run the command `df.rdd.getNumPartitions()` and it returns 16 as expected.

**Repartition**

then I run `df.repartition("department").rdd.getNumPartitions()` it returns 1 only.

no matter which combination of columns I put into the repartition function, it always gives me a dataframe with one partition only.

**Investigation**

If the number of partition is not placed in the repartition call, it use `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` by default (i.e. 200). So I run the command `df.repartition(200, "department").rdd.getNumPartitions()` and the repartitioning happens as expected.

**Problem**

Why is the repartitioning by column without providing the number of partitions not working?

Comment: What is the behavior of Apache Spark when reading approximately 1 GB of data? Does it automatically create multiple partitions for processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that repartition is working fine but AQE is coalescing partitions after shuffle as you have really small number of records

Sample code:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", True)

simpleData = [("James","Sales","NY",90000,34,10000),
    ("Michael","Sales","NY",86000,56,20000),
    ("Robert","Sales","CA",81000,30,23000),
    ("Maria","Finance","CA",90000,24,23000),
    ("Raman","Finance","CA",99000,40,24000),
    ("Scott","Finance","NY",83000,36,19000),
    ("Jen","Finance","NY",79000,53,15000),
    ("Jeff","Marketing","CA",80000,25,18000),
    ("Kumar","Marketing","NY",91000,50,21000),
    ("Kumar","Marketing","NY",91000,50,21000),
    ("Kumar","Marketing","NY",91000,50,21000)
  ]

schema = ["employee_name","department","state","salary","age","bonus"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=simpleData, schema = schema)
reaprtitioned = df.repartition("department")
reaprtitioned.show()
reaprtitioned.rdd.getNumPartitions()
```

This returns

```
Out[10]: 1
```

But with small change:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", False)
```

Number is equal to sql.shuffle.partitions

```
Out[11]: 200
```

Here is plan with AQE enabled:

```
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan (9)
+- == Final Plan ==
   * Project (5)
   +- AQEShuffleRead (4)
      +- ShuffleQueryStage (3), Statistics(sizeInBytes=912.0 B, rowCount=11, isRuntime=true)
         +- Exchange (2)
            +- * Scan ExistingRDD (1)
+- == Initial Plan ==
   CollectLimit (8)
   +- Project (7)
      +- Exchange (6)
         +- Scan ExistingRDD (1)
```

The initial plan in used when AQE is disabled